# How to use Model.fit which supports generators (after fit_generator deprecation)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have got this deprecation warning while using `Model.fit_generator` in tensorflow:

```
WARNING:tensorflow: Model.fit_generator (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use Model.fit, which supports generators.
```

How can I use `Model.fit` instead of `Model.fit_generator`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`Model.fit_generator` is deprecated starting from tensorflow 2.1.0 which is currently is in **rc1**.
You can find the documentation for tf-2.1.0-rc1 here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.1/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit

As you can see the first argument of the `Model.fit` can take a generator so just pass it your generator.

Answer (score 17):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.1/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) (emphasis mine):

> x: Input data. It could be
>
> - A Numpy array (or array-like), or a list of arrays (in case the model has multiple inputs).
> - A TensorFlow tensor, or a list of tensors (in case the model has multiple inputs).
> - A dict mapping input names to the corresponding array/tensors, if the
>   model has named inputs.
> - A tf.data dataset. Should return a tuple of either (inputs, targets) or (inputs, targets, sample_weights)
> - *A generator or keras.utils.Sequence returning (inputs, targets) or (inputs, targets, sample weights). A more detailed description of
>   unpacking behavior for iterator types (Dataset, generator, Sequence)
>   is given below.*

you can simply pass the generator to `Model.fit` as similar to `Model.fit_generator`

```
data_gen_train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.)

data_gen_valid = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.)

train_generator = data_gen_train.flow_from_directory(train_dir, target_size=(128,128), batch_size=128, class_mode="binary")

valid_generator = data_gen_valid.flow_from_directory(validation_dir, target_size=(128,128), batch_size=128, class_mode="binary")

model.fit(train_generator, epochs=2, validation_data=valid_generator)
```

Comment: You answer is incorrect or, I should say, only partially correct. valid_generator is not supported in model.fit

Comment: @sidk yes it is.

Comment: @sidk yes, it seems that `fit` param `validation_data` doesn't support dataset, generator, or keras.utils.Sequence and `validation_split` is not supported when param `x` is dataset, generator, or keras.utils.Sequence per `fit` info at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model