# Keras: fit_generator NotImplementedError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator

I am having problem with model.fit_generator, it throws me NotImplementedError  and I don't know where is the problem. Under the older Keras and TF it is working but after years I tried to update to new version and problem occured.

Whene I use:

```
model.fit_generator(generator=generator_train,
                        steps_per_epoch=generator_train.n / batch_size,
                        epochs=20,
                        verbose=1,
                        validation_data=generator_val,
                        validation_steps=math.ceil(generator_val.n / batch_size),
                        callbacks=[tb_callback, saver_callback],
                        use_multiprocessing=False,
                        initial_epoch=0
                        )
```

[I got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qiae.png)

My Generator:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import Iterator
from boxcars_image_transformations import alter_HSV, image_drop, unpack_3DBB, add_bb_noise_flip
import random

#%%

class BoxCarsDataGenerator(Iterator):
    def __init__(self, dataset, part, batch_size=8, training_mode=False, seed=None, generate_y = True, image_size = (224,224)):
        assert image_size == (224,224), "only images 224x224 are supported by unpack_3DBB for now, if necessary it can be changed"
        assert dataset.X[part] is not None, "load some classification split first"
        super().__init__(dataset.X[part].shape[0], batch_size, training_mode, seed)
        self.part = part
        self.generate_y = generate_y
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.image_size = image_size
        self.training_mode = training_mode
        if self.dataset.atlas is None:
            self.dataset.load_atlas()
        print("ANOOO TU SOM")

    #%%
    def __next__(self):
        with self.lock:
            index_array, current_index, current_batch_size = next(self.index_generator)
        x = np.empty([current_batch_size] + list(self.image_size) + [3], dtype=np.float32)
        for i, ind in enumerate(index_array):
            vehicle_id, instance_id = self.dataset.X[self.part][ind]
            vehicle, instance, bb3d = self.dataset.get_vehicle_instance_data(vehicle_id, instance_id)
            image = self.dataset.get_image(vehicle_id, instance_id) 
            if self.training_mode:
                image = alter_HSV(image) # randomly alternate color
                image = image_drop(image) # randomly remove part of the image
                bb_noise = np.clip(np.random.randn(2) * 1.5, -5, 5) # generate random bounding box movement
                flip = bool(random.getrandbits(1)) # random flip
                image, bb3d = add_bb_noise_flip(image, bb3d, flip, bb_noise) 

            image = unpack_3DBB(image, bb3d)      
            image = (image.astype(np.float32) - 116)/128.
            x[i, ...] = image
        if not self.generate_y:
            return x
        y = self.dataset.Y[self.part][index_array]
        return x, y
```

Comment: I think fit_generator is now deprecated as fit can handle generators too.

Comment: Why does your generator inherit Iterator? It will be better if you subclass Sequence instead.

Comment: Iterator inhertis from Sequence - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/Iterator

Answer (score -1):

EDIT 2: how to fix your issue:

You want to add :

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    return self.__next__()
```

In your `BoxCarsDataGenerator`

EDIT: after looking the problem in more detail, the problem comes from Keras' Iterator class ; when iterating over your `BoxCarsDataGenerator`, `__getitem__` returns:

```
self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
```

And `_get_batches_of_transformed_samples` is defined as:

```
def _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array):
    """Gets a batch of transformed samples.

    # Arguments
        index_array: Array of sample indices to include in batch.

    # Returns
        A batch of transformed samples.
    """
    raise NotImplementedError
```

In conclusion, you shouldn't use Keras' `Iterator` as it seems not to be implemented yet.

END OF EDIT

fit_generator is now deprecated as fit can handle generators too, you can take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59381897/12896974

Comment: I tried it with model.fit() too, but error is the same.

Comment: Can you add your entire tracelog?

Comment: Well, my entire tracelog is the same as image of error.

Comment: Yes, but still doesn't make sense to me where the problem is.

Comment: Honestly, I have looked at github's history for this file and it seems that this function was never implemented, you should move to another method to solve your problem.

Comment: This is git repository: https://github.com/JakubSochor/BoxCars what I try to update to new TF and Keras. Using old versions everything works. If you have time I would appreciate little help. Thanks.

Comment: I can't test the code right now, but a potential fix would be to add `def __getitem__(self, item):` (new line) `return self.__next__()` in your `BoxCarsDataGenerator` class. Hope this will fix it.

Comment: I have replaced ```__next__()``` with ```__getitem__(self, item)```, Iterator with Sequence and  change some other things and now it is working, thank you for help.